# Choosing n sets of integers that maximize the number of n-digit number permutations that satisfy an arbitrary condition

Tags: python

Say you have a list of all the n-digit numbers that satisfy a certain arbitrary condition. Now, you want to choose one set of k digits for each of the n digits that could be used to produce the greatest number of n-digit numbers on your list. So the total number of permutations will be k^n.

Alternatively, instead of trying to produce the greatest possible number of permutations that satisfy the condition, how would you maximize the ratio of permutations that satisfy the condition to permutations that don't.

I've been trying to think this problem through, and I just can't think up a solution very easily that isn't a brute-force approach. What am I missing?

EDIT: here's an example of what I mean. Let n=2 and k=4, that is, I want the program to find two lists, each containing 4 digits. By combining one digit from the first list with one digit from the second list, you can create a 2 digit number. For example let list1={0,1,4,7} and list2={0,2,3,8}. The set of two digit numbers I can create with these two lists is {00,02,03,08,10,12,13,18,40,42,43,48,70,72,73,78}.

Now I have an arbitrary condition that is tested by some external function, let's say in this case it's whether the two digit number is prime. For the lists I defined above, the subset of two digit numbers that I can create that satisfy this condition is {02,03,13,43,73}.

I have two separate goals:

1. Write a program that can determine which digits in list1 and list2 will produce the largest possible set of two digit numbers that satisfy my equation. For example, if I change list2 so it is now {1,3,7,9}, then the set of two-digit primes I can create becomes {01,03,07,11,13,17,19,41,43,47,71,73,79}. So in this case (assuming I'm right), the number is 13.
2. Write a program that can determine which digits in list1 and list2 will produce the set of two-digit numbers with the largest ratio of elements that satisfy my condition to elements that don't. For the example with the new list2 values, the ratio is 13/16 because 09, 49, and 77 are not prime.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: @James I edited the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are interested in a solution where the external function is flexible and not just about prime numbers, correct?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: This answer is not complete, but may steer others in the right direction.*

**First, enumeration of all satisfying values is required:**

Any algorithm will have to check n-digit numbers in some order to see if they satisfy the condition. Suppose that the algorithm tests the numbers n1, n2, n3, ...

Then you can imagine an arbitrary condition which only holds true for numbers that are very close to the end of that enumeration. In other words, for any algorithm, we can always come up with an arbitrary condition for which the algorithm performs arbitrarily poorly either in terms of time or accuracy.

**Relation to the [Maximum Density Subgraph](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~barna/paper/icalp-final.pdf) problem:**

This problem is equivalent to finding a maximum density subgraph in a multipartite graph.

We can convert a problem instance into a multipartite graph as follows. Each independent set in the graph corresponds to a decimal place, and each vertex corresponds to a possible value in that decimal place. For example, with n=2, the first independent set would be 0_, 1_, 2_, ... and the second independent set would be _0, _1, _ 2, ..., . Edges correspond to satisfying values. For example, if all primes are satisfying, we would have edges (0_, _ 2), (0_, _ 3), ..., (1_, _1)... etc.

Now selecting k digits for each of the n decimal places is equivalent to selecting k nodes from each of the parts of the graph. We want to make this selection to maximize the number of edges preserved in the final graph, or to maximize the fraction of edges to non-edges. This is the same as trying to find a subgraph with maximum density under the described constraint.

As described in the linked paper, **Maximum Density Subgraph is NP-Hard**. This problem might be slightly easier because of the structural constraints on the graph and limit to 10 nodes per part, but I'm not sure. **I have a feeling this problem might be NP-Hard as well.**

Comment: I know that the program will have to check every possible n-digit numbers, but does it need to check every possible list1, list2, ..., listN as well?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on the question the first time. I expanded my answer but it is not a full solution. Maybe it will help you or others though. Good luck!